# How to get Storybook to use a project's CSS variables

Tags: storybook, css-variables

I am using Storybook with a React project that also uses styled-components. Many of those style definitions access CSS variable values that are defined in `:root` in an `index.css` file at the root of the `src` directory. All of the CSS variables defined this way are just placeholders for colors. However, when the components are rendered in Storybook the values of the CSS variables aren't being accessed and so those colors never render/display.

Is there a way, either via a plugin or configuration, to make it so the CSS variables I am defining in my `index.css` file are accessible to the components when they are rendered in Storybook?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can import CSS file in the `.storybook/preview.js` file:

```js
import '../src/index.css';

// ... rest of the settings
```

This way it will be available across all pages in your Storybook.

Comment: Durn it I found this out separately and had meant to put up my own answer so I could get the points! But you've got it @crazko, thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer just creates a parse error.  Leave out some other detail?

Comment: That depends on your configuration and preferences. Better to check the official documentation: https://storybook.js.org/docs/configure/styling-and-css.